# SELECT Columns FROM other Table but Should Return Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, report

I am working with small project for sales my some table like this

**sale_order**

```
+----+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
| so | date       | po_num | structure_id | customer_id | quantity | rate     |
+----+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
|  2 | 2015-01-09 | 23     |            1 |          11 |     1234 |   0.0000 |
|  3 | 2015-09-02 | 1234   |            1 |          12 |     1000 |   0.0000 |
| 12 | 2015-09-01 | 1234   |            3 |          12 |   100000 |  12.0000 |
| 13 | 2015-09-01 | 232    |            4 |          11 |     1000 | 123.0000 |
| 14 | 2015-09-01 | 1212   |            4 |          12 |    10000 | 123.0000 |
| 15 | 2015-11-04 | 3424   |            1 |          11 |     2555 |   0.0000 |
| 16 | 2015-11-04 | 343    |            2 |          11 |   233333 |   0.0000 |
| 17 | 2015-12-02 | 12345  |            3 |          13 |    10000 |   0.0000 |
+----+------------+--------+--------------+-------------+----------+----------+
```

**Structure**

```
+----+------------------+
| id | job_name         |
+----+------------------+
|  4 | ketchup          |
|  3 | bubble           |
|  2 | masala           |
|  1 | xyz              |
+----+------------------+
```

**customer**

```
+-------------+-------------------------------+
| customer_id | customer_name                 |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
|          11 | customer 1                    |
|          12 | xyz                           |
|          13 | abc                           |
+-------------+-------------------------------+
```

**dispatch**

```
+----+----+------------+-----------+
| id | so | date       | delivered |
+----+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 |  2 | 2015-09-02 |    123.00 |
|  2 | 12 | 2015-09-02 |    203.00 |
|  3 | 12 | 2015-09-17 |    213.00 |
|  4 |  2 | 2015-05-11 |    123.00 |
|  5 | 14 | 2015-11-06 |    233.00 |
+----+----+------------+-----------+
```

i am to create a report which show total order quantity along with associated deliveries and balance. with programming language like PHP C# or other i can do with two time request to the mysql server first time get order

```
SELECT
  so.po_num,
  so.date,
  c.customer_name,
  st.job_name,
  so.rate,
  so.quantity
FROM
  sale_order AS so
JOIN
  structure AS st ON so.structure_id = st.id
JOIN
  customer AS c ON so.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

then with this id get there deliveries

```
SELECT
  d.date,
  d.id AS reference,
  d.net_weight AS deliverd
FROM
  dispatch AS d
WHERE
  d.so = so.id
```

but i want to generate all thing with one single query is there anyway to achieve this result directly with mysql query

**desired result:** with or without **-**

```
SO #  | DATE      | JOB NAME  | RATE  | ORDER QUANTITY  | D DATE    | REFREENCE  |  D QUANTITY  | BALANCE
1       2/2/2015    ABC         XXX     XXX               4/2/2015    D-12          XX            XX
 -        -           -           -       -               5/2/2015    D-22          XX            XX
 -        -           -           -       -               7/2/2015    D-50          XX            XX  
2       2/2/2015    ABC         XXX     XXX               4/2/2015    D-14          XX            XX
 -        -           -           -       -               5/2/2015    D-26          XX            XX
 -        -           -           -       -               7/2/2015    D-58          XX            XX
```

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: Do you like to create relationship b/w tables?

Comment: Where does SO 1 come from? I just cannot see how the data set corresponds with the result set. Presumably, it doesn't, but then why bother?

Comment: this is dumy 1 should be replace any of sale order id

Comment: yes i already created relationship between tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@humaira I think this is not possible to do all the things  in one single query. probably your doing write in two parts.